# How do I force razor to switch back to client side code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've got the following code in one of my views

```
@if (ViewBag.LoginInfo != null)
{
    var loginToken = "@ViewBag.LoginInfo.Token";
    var loginUser = "@ViewBag.LoginInfo.UserNameJs";
    var notifyUrl = "@ViewBag.LoginInfo.NotificationUrl";
}
```

The code between { } should be rendered to the page as javascript, however it seems to be getting run as serverside code. I'm aware razor switches back to client code when it sees html in this case the code is valid as C# and javascript. How to I force everthing between { } to be written to the page as javasript?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried surrounding it in a text tag?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could wrap them in `<text>` tags:

```
@if (ViewBag.LoginInfo != null)
{
    <text>
        var loginToken = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.LoginInfo.Token);
        var loginUser = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.LoginInfo.UserNameJs);
        var notifyUrl = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.LoginInfo.NotificationUrl);
    </text>
}
```

Also notice how I have safely encoded the values. Your example will produce invalid javascript if for example your token contains the `"` character. You should never be mixing javascript and server side values without using a safe serializer as shown in my example.

Answer (score 14):

Alternatively use `@:`

```
@if (ViewBag.LoginInfo != null)
{
    @:var loginToken = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.LoginInfo.Token);
    @:var loginUser = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.LoginInfo.UserNameJs);
    @:var notifyUrl = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.LoginInfo.NotificationUrl);     
}
```